# "ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query" while loading data

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am getting an error when I try to load data into my MySQL (MariaDB actually) table using the `load data` command:

```
load data local infile '/tmp/my_data.tsv' 
into table my_schema.my_table
fields terminated by '\t' 
optionally enclosed by '"'
escaped by '\\'
lines terminated by '\n';
```

Trying the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189152/error-2013-hy000-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query-while-droppin) did not work.

Comment: Why downvote? I wasted almost an hour of my time trying to figure this out. And I was contemplating deleting the table because other posts said you get this error if your table is corrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, MySQL gives this obscure error message when the data you are loading breaks a foreign key constraint (described in more detail [here](http://database.javascriptag.com/312_19364850/)).

I managed to get the correct error message by executing the `load data` command directly from the command line. *i.e.* running:

```
mysql -u username -p --local-infile --execute= \
"load data local infile '/tmp/my_data.tsv' into table my_schema.my_table \
fields terminated by '\t' optionally enclosed by '\"' escaped by '\\\\';"
```

gave the error message:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`my_schema`.`my_table`, CONSTRAINT `other_table` FOREIGN KEY
(`id`) REFERENCES `other_table` (`id`))
```

After removing rows that violated the foreign key constraint, I was able to import my data.